# Each is not working as supposed with Handlebar

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In an app that use Handlebar 4.0.3, I have this simple template :

```
{{#each certificates}}
  <tr>
    <td data-title='Certification'>{{this}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

And I use compile it like this :

```
result = template(certificates: ['test'])
```

I have this result :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed tablesorter">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td data-title="Certification">[object Object]</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I think I should have "test" instead of "[object Object]".

I tried with this template :

```
{{#each certificates}}
<tr>
  <td data-title='Certification'>{{this}}</td>
  <td data-title='Certification'>{{name}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

And this JavaScript :

```
result = template({ certificates: [{name: 'Name'}]})
```

And I have tyhis result :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed tablesorter">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td data-title="Certification">[object Object]</td>
    <td data-title="Certification"></td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, `{{name}}` gives nothing instead of "Name".

Am I doing something wrong?

## Edit 1

I found the problem.

I have this html :

```
  <div id='modal-site'>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {{#each site.certificates}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{this.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I do this `$('#modal-site').html()`, I have this result :

```
{{#each site.certificates}}

{{/each}}
<table>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>{{this.name}}</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

With the `each` is outside so handlebars cannot work. Do you have an idea of the solution ?

Comment: Try `{{this.name}}` in HTML (for that second implementation of template).

Comment: Your second implementation should work as is https://jsbin.com/sicijiwuba/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @RoyMiloh, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

For the second implementation of your template, you should use `{{this.name}}` in HTML if you want to access the string data.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle of entire solution. I can't see that `site` object in your script that would have a `certificates` array within.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```
{{#each certificates as |cert|}}
<tr>
  <td data-title='Certification'>{{cert}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```